# Cakephp how to pass array from view to controller

Tags: cakephp

Using Cakephp 2 i am trying to select one or many records clicking into a checkbox, from a list 
named my_id[] :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="my_id[]" value="<?php echo $Myobj['My']['id']; ?>
```

I have a link to the controller processBatch method but did not know how to pass the array of selected data using the checkbox into the view file.

```
<?= $this->Html->link('Batch process','proccessBatch')?>
```

I am trying :

```
public function proccessBatch( ) //array of $ids  
{        
    pr($this->request);
```

But did not see $this-request->data. How can i get the checkbox selected values ?

Comment: You can post data into the **proccessBatch()** function by submitting form. then you will get the data into **"$this->request->data"** array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a sample for you below.

> Here is my view

```
    <?php
    //sample list of items with 'id'=>'name
    $arrayList = [
        0=>'item 1',
        1=>'Item 2',
        2=>'Item 3'
    ];
    //create the form
    echo $this->Form->create('listofitems',array('novalidate' => true));
    //generate the checkboxes by looping through the items(this is just one way of doing it)
        for($i=0;$i<count($arrayList);$i++){
            //concatenate the value of the id ($i in my case) with the name
            // of the field to uniquely identify it.
            echo $this->Form->checkbox("my_id".$i);
        }
    echo $this->Form->end('save');//end form and save button
    ?>
```

> Here is my controller and its action

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class SampleController extends AppController {

    public function arrays(){
        pr($this->request->data); //just pr the posted data
    }

}
?>
```

> And the result of the pr line in the controller

```
Array
(
    [listofitems] => Array
        (
            [my_id0] => 1
            [my_id1] => 0
            [my_id2] => 1
        )

)
```

Hope this helps you with your question. Do note that only the **checked items have a value of 1** while **unchecked ones have a value of 0**